# How to update multi property value of an object in array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The following is my database schema update operation:

```
db.school_student.update({ _id: "003" }, {
    $set: {
        "result": [
            {
                "_id": "001",
                "isPassed": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "002",
                "isPassed": false,
            },
            {
                "_id": "003",
                "isPassed": false
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I want to change **ALL** the property values of `"isPassed"` to `true`. Is there any way to update this? I have been struggling with this the whole day :(

Comment: Can you show the Mongo db doc also

Answer (score 0):

```
db.school_student.update({},{$Set :{"result.isPassed" : true}}
```

this should update all the documents in school_student collection and set isPassed to true.

Comment: The school_student collection has _id: 001, 002, 003, but i want to update only _id:003

Comment: db.school_student.update({"result._id":003},{$Set :{"result.isPassed" : true}} will update result -> is passed only for id 003